# Adding drop shadow to a cutout box

Tags: css

I can make the following box and its cutout triangle (with border trick) using CSS, only without the background pattern with a slight noise.

[image]

Is is possible to make the cutout triangle with the background pattern?

Also stuck with the drop shadow! How can I add it?

Should I better switch back to the old method, using spans and background images around the box?

Edit: Solution with one background image.

[image]

Comment: You would need two or three elements to achieve the cutout with just HTML/CSS. Why not just use the image?

Comment: Yes, I guess it's better for this one. I may just use a triangle image with the proper drop shadow and add it under the box with a negative margin to fit the rest of the the box's shadow, right?

Comment: That should work. It may cause side effects though, extending outside of the box.

Comment: You can try using an inside shadow on the cutout color, though the it'll be tricky to match it with the outside shadow seamlessly.

Comment: put your html and css in a fiddle. You can get what you are looking for with transforms. I have done this. Here is a dabblet I created http://dabblet.com/gist/5042891 which is similar to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: This is my image version: [Image](http://i.imgur.com/IkEiCVx.png) I think I'll go with this because Sujesh's solution does not work with drop shadows at the bottom of the box.

Answer (score -1):

I've just used a bit of CSS `box-shadow` magic; so here's an approximation of what I think you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/jMEL8/