# CSS: "Indentation" in border below active menu item

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a simple Bootstrap navbar menu, which works great, but I want to add a little visual indicator to the bottom of the menu div to show which menu item is currently active.

This seems like it should be easy, but particularly notice that the drop shadow needs to move with the indentation - how do we do something like this?

A picture is worth a thousand words, added one below.

*EDIT* Added Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/1463/

HTML

```
<div class="navbar navbar-gradient navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" /></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" /></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');

/* gradient for main navigation bar */
.navbar-gradient {
    background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #e5e5e5 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#e5e5e5)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#e5e5e5',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

    /* drop shadow */
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #888888;
}
```

[image]

Comment: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: If you won't have better ideas, maybe try to make small image with that indicator including shadows and position it relative to active icon?

Comment: Some code or fiddle is worth a thousand pictures.

Comment: The image idea might work, although straight CSS would be better.

I get that fiddles help, I'll try to make one, but... we're talking about adding an indentation to the bottom of a rectangle, right?

Comment: fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/1463/

Comment: see if my answer here helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15507345/adding-drop-shadow-to-a-cutout-box/15508269#15508269

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution with a `.png` image :

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/s97zJ/16/)**

I added this to you css:

```
li.active{position:relative;}
li.active::after{
    content:"";
    background: transparent url("http://i41.tinypic.com/29ofuoh.png") no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 15px 17px;
    height:17px;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:43px;
    left:0;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! How did you make the .png, by the way? I tried making one but I'm kinda crap with Photoshop.

Comment: it comes from the image you put in your question ;) I just cropped it. If you plan on using it, you should resize it to displaying size though

Answer (score 0):

Probably needs a little more tweaking but here is a 100% CSS solution.

[image: triangle]

[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/1468/)

```
    @import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');

.triangle {
    margin-top:-7px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-left:31px;
}
.triangle::after {
    content:'';
    border-bottom: 0;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    z-index: 2;
    box-shadow: inset 2px -4px 9px #888;
}
.triangle-cover {
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:1px;
    margin-left:-7px;
    z-index:10;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: solid 17px white;
    border-left: solid 14px transparent;
    border-right: solid 14px transparent; 
}
```

and in each `li` that you want `active` (and you might have to use a little JS to insert these elements into the DOM of the li is active...)

```
        <li class="active"><a href="#"><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/ampeross/qetto-2/48/settings-icon.png" /></a>
            <div class="triangle"><span class="triangle-cover"></span></div>
        </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like the following. At least if you don't want to use images and don't mind CSS transforms (Other options may include using an image, drawing the thing with CSS backgrounds or SVG maybe.)

[image: Example]

<kbd>[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NzmgH/)</kbd>

```
.box{
    height: 40px;
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #888;
    background: #f4f4f4;
}

.box::after{
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: inset 10px 10px 3px -7px #888;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -8px;
    right: 50px;
}
```